# Ancestor with a specific color

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees

During a lot of algorithm competitions I met colored tree questions and there have been multiple cases where I though of different approaches.
I'm curious what is the best way of solving the following problem:

Given a tree with N nodes: 2 <= N <= 100 000. Every node has a color c : 2 <= c <= 100 000. You are supposed answer Q queries 2 <= Q <= 100 000. There are 2 types of queries:

1. what is the closest ancestor of node V that has same color as V
2. change the color of node V to other color (possible not existing in the set of already used colors).

Obviously the brute force solution O(N) for a query is not accepted. I assume that there is a way of having a query solved in Log(N) or Log(N)^2.

From what I have searched this looks like the "Marked Ancestor Problem" but I can't find something good to read.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What approaches have you considered?  You might just need to spend more time brainstorming possible ideas.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises / competition problems for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Also, you might want to edit your question to improve its formatting.

Comment: Sorry @D.W. This is not a an exercise or a competition problem (I'm not in school for quite some time now - I just try to learn new algorithms via different competitions online - usually [link](https://www.codechef.com/). While I was solving different problems I have thought of this problem. Regarding the formatting please excuse me - this is the first question posted here since most of the time I use the competitions internal blogs, but since this is an external problem I tried to found the right place to ask this. A quick search on Google showed that this is the "algorithm guru questions".

Comment: Regarding the approach I was thinking -> for every node while doing a dfs maintain a persistent trie for every color. For the first type of question I would simply query the closest left leaf of the current node's leaf (if exists). For the second type of query I'm supposed to erase a node from persistent trie and find the place where to add this, but here I got stuck.

Comment: should I post the questions in another place ?